# System of equations with with 3 variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Is it possible to find solutions of this system expressed with $a$:

$x^2+y^2+xy=a$
 $x^2+z^2+zx=a$
 $y^2+z^2-yz=a$

Thanks for help.

Comment: What are $(2)-(1)$  and $(3)-(1)$?

Answer (score 0):

It is not always possible, at least not over the real numbers, to find solutions of this system. We obtain either $y^2=a$ or $x^2=a$, which has both no real solution for $a<0$. We argue as follows: $(2)-(1)$ gives
$$
(z-y)(x+y+z)=0.
$$
For $z=y$ we obtain $y^2=a$ from $(3)$, and this has no solution for $a<0$. For $a\ge 0$ it has a solution, namely $y^2=a$, $x(x+y)=0$.

In the other case, $y\neq z$ we obtain the solution $z=-x-y$, and $y(x+y)=0$, $a=x^2$.